# How to run Java when C drive is not the default in CMD prompt?

Tags: java, cmd, javac

I am facing following scenario:

1. Win XP Machine, 2003 SP, jre7
2. No admin rights to even set class path via my computer properties
3. CMD prompt shows a local drive as user drive instead of C
4. Thus unable to execute following command:-

`c:\program files\Java\jre7\bin` 
It says C:\program files isn't recognized as an internal or external command.

1. Tried to change directry to C but not successful

What I want:

1. To be able to compile and run java files from CMD prompt
2. Setting up path from CMD

I hope it ia not too much to expect in such an unreasonably restricted development environment.

Comment: if you get a command line type `set` and see if JAVA_HOME is set.  If it is it will say where java is installed.

Comment: `Environment variable JAVA_HOME not defined`. But when I type `Java -version` it shows details of current intallation.

Comment: The above "command" isn't one.  You need to include `java`.  And "program files" needs to be in quotes in M$'s strange way.  `c:\"program files"\Java\jre7\bin\java`

Comment: If `java -version` works you don't need to specify the path to use the `java` command.  You may still need to specify `-classpath`, et al, though.

Comment: I don't even have internet on the machine. Typing from my phone, so little slow. @hotlicks here's how I tried `U:\> c:\"program files"\Java\jre7\bin\java` it shows a java oracle dump...

Comment: I want to delete and close this. But I am truly concern about the effort that answers took to help me out. The b***** machines has no jdk....no way to pull a tools.jar to compile so how in the world it will ever compile a Java file... I was totally blind too. Thanks everyone for prompt support.

Comment: If you just have the JRE and not the JDK you don't have `javac` and can't compile on that box.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you can try this

set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java(YOUR JDK FOLDER) eg. jdk1.5.0_14\bin";%PATH%

so enter set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin";%PATH% but make sure it matches your JDK install folder.

If you need anymore help please let me know.

Comment: I guess I managed to set the class path using the snippet you provided. But I am unable to compile the `.java` file using `javac` command. What do you suggest?

Comment: Your answer is awesome in setting the path. But please see my last comment. The machine is totally javaless... sigh

Comment: If you would like, and if you have Teamviewer I could remote connect to your computer and fix your problem for you. Please let me know, you can send me a private email if you would like.

Comment: cheers mate! But it wasn't my own pc. It was a pc belonges to a poor developer team in a client office. The system admins are so strict and it is banking environment. My pc is all good ;-)