# Java SE Development Kit 8u20 Install Options

Tags: java

I want to install JAVA from the link:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

I am using Windows 7 (32 Bit OS) in Dell Vostro Laptop with Intel Core i5 2.50 GHz

Now in the link, there are 2 installations for Windows:

Windows x86    161.08 MB     jdk-8u20-windows-i586.exe
 Windows x64    173.08 MB     jdk-8u20-windows-x64.exe

Which one I had to select to install JAVA 8?

Comment: If you are using 32 bit OS chose also 32 bit (x86) version. Anyway installer of 64 bit version should detect that 32 bit OS is not appropriate and will not let you install Java this version, so you don't really have any choice here.

Answer (score 0):

`Windows x86 161.08 MB jdk-8u20-windows-i586`. You cannot run 64bit applications on a 32bit Operating System. You have no choice but to go with 32bit (x86)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run Windows x86 161.08 MB jdk-8u20-windows-i586.exe unless your computer has a minimum of 4GB of RAM... Also you will need to look at this other post of mine to setup your environment variables in Windows. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22368507/3250752. Your environment variables need to be setup if you intend to use the command prompt or CMD in Windows to compile your applications and run them....